"Cannot use import statement outside module" error when attempting to read from a PDF using Node
I am attempting to read content from a PDF file using Node with the Pdfreader module, but it is giving me the following error in the terminal:
(node:31780) Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.
(Use node --trace-warnings ... to show where the warning was created)
/Users/Zayan/index.js:1
import { PdfReader } from "pdfreader";
^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
at internalCompileFunction (node:internal/vm:128:18)
at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1279:20)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1331:27)
at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1426:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1205:32)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1021:12)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:142:12)
at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49
This is my index.js so far (I have not created any files other than this and it is stored in my user folder):
import {PdfReader} from "pdfreader";

new PdfReader().parseFileItems("600067301-2024-04-03.pdf",(err,item) => {
    if(err) console.log(error)
    else if (!item) console.warn("end of file")
    else if (item.text) console.log(item.txt)
})


Search: [javascript] Cannot use import statement outside module : > 900 results

Please change your file suffix to .mjs
or
Add "type": "module" to package.json.
